# Streaming HttpResponse through Owin

Tags: c#, stream, owin, dotnet-httpclient

I have a `HttpResponse` object as a result of `HttpClient.SendAsync()` call. The response has a [`chunked` transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) and results in 1.5 GB of data.

I want to pass this data through OWIN pipeline. To do this I need to convert it to a stream. Simplified code to do this is:

```cs
public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
{
    var httpContent = GetHttpContent();
    var responseStream = (Stream)environment["owin.ResponseBody"];
    await httpContent.CopyToAsync(responseStream);
}
```

However, the last line results in copying the entire stream to the memory. And when I use `wget` to download the data directly from the backend server, it is downloaded successfully and shows a progress bar (although it doesn't know the overall size since it is chunked). But when I use `wget` to download data from my OWIN-hosted application it sticks on sending the request.

How should I stream this data through an OWIN pipeline to prevent copying it to memory?

**EDIT**

This is how I get the `HttpResponse`:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
// …and then:
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = uri, Method = HttpMethod.Get })
{
    return client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your HttpClient call? Most HttpClient methods buffer the response by default. You need one that doesn't, like GetStreamAsync or SendAsync with HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead.

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Looks ok, (except use await instead of Result).

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is in IIS? System.Web also buffers responses: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.bufferoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

See `server.DisableResponseBuffering` in
https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OWIN%20Keys&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Yes, it is hosted on IIS. But we don't use System.Web at all (we even don't have reference to it).

Comment: OWIN on IIS uses System.Web (Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb)